# How to hide system/admin folders when viewing a SharePoint site in Explorer View

Tags: sharepoint-2013, explorer

We're developing a new SharePoint 2013 site and we want our users to be able to easily save files to SharePoint. We have about 100 site collections and each represents a Property that we own and contains all the documents related to that Property. Obviously, the easiest way to ensure a new document is created in the correct location is to first navigate to the document library, then click "New Document". Unfortunately, we anticipate most users will create the document first, then want to choose where to save it. Our users are not so computer savvy and are accustomed to file shares.

I've tried using "Connect To Office" but have had mixed results. Ideally, I would like this link to be to the site collection root so the user can see all the document libraries on the site rather than a single document library.

1. Any tips on using "Connect To Office"? What permissions or GPOs need to be set up so this works smoothly? We have an SSL site and our users are running Win 7,8 & 10 and also use Office 2010 & 2013.
2. Is there any way to hide the system/admin folders at the root level of the site collection in Explorer View? The site collections are publishing sites, so there are many additional folders and it's difficult to see which are relevant to the users - plus I'd like to hide them to help with security. There are approximately 25 folders that they should not see.

TIA

Answer (score -1):

I have the exact same scenario.

I have had quite good success mapping the root SP site as a mapped drive.  Users can easily browse the SP site libraries as they would folders on the network.  It was a bit tricky to get it reliable but now is working very well.

Would also like to know the answer to hiding all the publishing system libraries.  I tried setting them to hidden in SP Designer without success.

Mike

Comment: Hi Mike! I ended up making a folder on a shared drive, placing shortcuts to all the site collections that we wanted available to users, and then adding a shortcut to the shared drive folder in the "Favourites" or "Quick Links" folder. The users then can access the sites fairly easily. But the explorer view of the site collection changes depending on the user's environment. The latest version of Windows + Office shows a SharePoint view of the libraries and the system libraries are hidden. So, that's ok, but still not sure what to do about older environments.